# Arrow with a point on it and cancelled arrow

Tags: symbols, arrows

I stumbled over this kind of arrows and can't find any reference to it (since I not even know how they're called).

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know the right command for those? Or are this  constructed elements?

Comment: `\overset{\bullet}{\to}` with `amsmath` whould work; for the second one, look at the `centernot` package.  The canonical reference is [How to look up a symbol](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14)

Comment: For the second one, the `amssymb` package offers `\nrightarrow`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{centernot}

\begin{document}
$X \overset{\bullet}{\to} Y$

$X \overset{\bullet\mkern3mu}{\to} Y$

$X \overset{\scalebox{0.5}{$\bullet$}\mkern3mu}{\to} Y$

$X \overset{\raisebox{-1ex}{\scalebox{0.5}{$\bullet$}}\mkern3mu}{\to} Y$

$\nrightarrow$

$\not\rightarrow$

$\centernot{\rightarrow}$
\end{document}
```

yields

[image: some right arrows]

Comment: the dot would look better a bit to the left.  insert `\mkern-3mu` (within the braces) after the `\bullet`.  the dot also looks too high, but that's harder to fix.

Comment: The dot seems to me to be too large. I would recommend `\stackrel` instead of `\overset`.

Comment: @tohecz `\stackrel` does not change anything for me, at least here.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `\stackrel{{}_\bullet}{\rightarrow}` (doable with `\overset` the very same way). And you're right, the result is exactly same. Just that `\overset` does quite a lot of unnecessary things that `\stackrel` does not. As well, `\stackrel` seems to be semantically correct ("stack" something on a "relation" symbol).